# Firebase Posting Dictionary in iOS Swift - Can't get get data to load in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I am posting to Firebase using a Post Dictionary. See code below:

```
class Post  {

    let eventImageURL: String?
    let postID: String?

    static var feed:[Post]?


    init(id: String?, eventImageURL: String?)
    {
        self.postID = id
        self.eventImageURL = eventImageURL
    }

    static func initWithPostID(postID: String, postDict: [String: String]) -> Post? {
        guard let eventImageURL = postDict["eventImageURL"] else {
            // Conditiions if failed...
            print("Invalid Post Dictionary")
            return nil
        }

        return Post(id: postID, eventImageURL: eventImageURL)
    }

   func dictValue() -> [String: String] {
        var postDict = [String: String]()
        postDict["eventImageURL"] = eventImageURL
    return postDict
    }

  }
```

I am then trying to call each post into a TableView using this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    postRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let posts = snapshot.value as? [String: [String: String]] else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        Post.feed?.removeAll()
        for (postID, post) in  posts {
            let newPost = Post.initWithPostID(postID: postID, postDict: post)!
            Post.feed?.append(newPost)
        }
        Post.feed = Post.feed?.reversed()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }, withCancel : { (error) in
            print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    })
}
```

When I call `Post.feed.count` it returns zero (*i.e. empty string*). What am I missing? It also means I can't view any data in TableView.

The Post Dictionary works when posting to Firebase, a typical post looks like this:

```
["-KRTbOfj2vswyFntPdnp": ["eventImageURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b.co/appspotm/o/EventImages%2F-KRTbFz1lpnACmQucPLQ%2FeventImage.jpg?alt=media&token=b013fd9f-cf36-4139-a8cc-afa5f1daa8b3"]]
```